# Having some trouble setting up my webpack config

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am following a few tutorials, but mainly the one by Dan Abramov on setting up react hot loader but I am having some issues.  I think I have a basic configuration working, however hot reloading of component does not seem to work, so obviously the hot loader set up is wrong :(

When I change a component, my browser console logs this:

```
The following modules couldn't be hot updated: (Full reload needed)
This is usually because the modules which have changed (and their parents) do not know how to hot reload themselves. See http://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html for more details.
- ./app/components/Home/index.jsx
```

To start off, here is my file structure:

```
.
|++[app]
|----[actions]
|----[modules]
|----[reducers]
|----[store]
|----index.html
|----index.js
|--[config]
|----server.js
|----webpack.config.js
|--[node_modules]
|--package.json
```

Here's my webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
  devtool: isProd ? null : 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    path.resolve('app/index.js')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve( 'app/'),
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: [
          'babel'
        ],
        include: path.resolve('.'),
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss!sass'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  postcss: [
    autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 3 versions'] })
  ]
};
```

And my server.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
var webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
var config = require('./webpack.config');
var path = require('path');
var app = new (require('express'))();
var port = 3000;

var compiler = webpack(config);
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, { noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath }));
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve('app/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.info('started on localhost://%s.', port);
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you considered using https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app ?

Comment: i am trying to learn webpack basics since i was using something like that before :(

Answer (score 0):

The `react-hot` loader is missing within your `module.loaders` array. [More into this](http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/#configuration).

> Next we need to tell Webpack to use React Hot Loader for the components. If you configured Webpack for React, you may already use babel-loader (ex 6to5-loader) or jsx-loader for JS(X) files. Find that line in webpack.config.js and put react-hot before other loader(s).

So you need to add the `react-hot` loader before your `babel` loader, like so:

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loader: 'react-hot',
  exclude: /node_modules/
}
```

And also you need to install the `react-hot-loader` module if you haven't already.

```
npm i -D react-hot-loader
```

Comment: thanks!  i actually have that installed, however the documentation said to put that into the babelrc file.  I tried what you did, but then I get a warning that says that I should put that into the babelrc which I did.

Comment: Are you using the newer react-hot-loader 3.0 version? Seems like the module.loaders to .babelrc migration for `react-hot` only applies to v3 as documented [here](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/tree/next-docs/docs). There is also a [react-hot-boilerplate v3](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate/tree/next) repo you could start from.